# Webview and camera access

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have a `web app` (secured via SSL) that has an access to `camera`.It shows `camera` captures in a `canvas`. It worked perfectly in the browser. However, I want the `camera` content to show in the `Webview` in my app.
Here is my code in the method `onCreate`:

```
    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://myvideoapp.me");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Here is permissions i used in my manifest.XML

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ask permission if you're coding android +4.4

Into your MainActivity, inside your class, use this if you want to ask for CAMERA permission:

```
private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 0;


private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    List listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList();

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, (String[])     listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),     REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And also you have to check it inside your onCreate void function like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    if (!checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        return; 
    }

.........
```